# Monitor progress of Virtuoso bulk data load

Tags: dbpedia, virtuoso

I am loading DBPedia (file by file) into Virtuoso using the standard `ld_dir` command in `isql`.

**Question:** Is there a way to monitor the progress of loading a single file?

I understand that `select ll_file, ll_status from db.dba.load_list;` gives `1` for files that are in progress, and `status()` displays the current active statements and their running times.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I could find is to run `status('c');` and monitor the `File Size` in the displayed output. If the file size is increasing, then there is something being done. But I could not know the progress or percentage of work done or get an ETA.